# Add get current date to this script?

Tags: php, plugins

I'm using this plugin called showtime. I like it but one problem, I want to call the schedule for the current day. Some part of this plugin calls for the shortcode to get all days and schedule of those days.

What do i add to the code below to make sure it gets the schedule for the current day.

```
function showtime_schedule_handler($atts, $content=null, $code=""){

global $wpdb;
global $showtimeTable;

//Get the current schedule, divided into days
$daysOfTheWeek = array("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday");

$schedule = array();

$output = '';

foreach ($daysOfTheWeek as $day) {
    //Add this day's shows HTML to the $output array
    $showsForThisDay =  $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare ( "SELECT * FROM $showtimeTable WHERE dayOfTheWeek = '$day' ORDER BY startTime" ));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think use time function to slove .

```
<?php
$nextWeek = time() + (7 * 24 * 60 * 60);
                   // 7 days; 24 hours; 60 mins; 60secs
echo 'Now:       '. date('Y-m-d') ."\n";
echo 'Next Week: '. date('Y-m-d', $nextWeek) ."\n";
// or using strtotime():
echo 'Next Week: '. date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 week')) ."\n";
?>
```

The above example will output something similar to:

Now:       2005-03-30
Next Week: 2005-04-06
Next Week: 2005-04-06

Comment: I don't want it to say next week, I want it to only display the calendar for the current day